# How To Write - If Item Does Not Match Multiple Numbers - In Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a grid of buttons 11 buttons x 7 buttons. I need to check the tags of the buttons that are not on the outside edge of the grid. My current solution is to exclude the tags that are on the outside edge. The buttons are in an `outlet collection`. So the tags I need to exclude are 0-10, 21, 32, 43, 54, 65, 76, 0, 11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66-76.

How do you check if an item in an if-statement, that's inside of a for-loop, matches multiple numbers? You can see the code below will become a mess if I play it out with 28 different `||` conditions. The numbers I'm trying to match are not in sequence.

```
for item in buttonOutlets {

    if item.tag != 0 || item.tag != 1 || item.tag != 2  {

    var tag = item.tag
    var tagMinusOne: Int? = Int(item.tag) - 1
    var tagMinusTen: Int? = Int(item.tag) - 10
    var tagMinusEleven: Int? = Int(item.tag) - 11
    var tagMinusTwelve: Int? = Int(item.tag) - 12
    var titleLabel = item.titleLabel?.text
    var minusTwelve: String? = buttonOutlets[tagMinusTwelve!].titleLabel?.text!
    var minusOne: String? = buttonOutlets[tagMinusOne!].titleLabel?.text!

    }

}
```

Here is what works but is a mess. Note that the tags are not in a perfect range. Updated code:

```
func checkForMatchingCells() {

for item in buttonOutlets {

    var tag = item.tag as Int

    if tag != 0
    && tag != 1
    && tag != 2
    && tag != 3
    && tag != 4
    && tag != 5
    && tag != 6
    && tag != 7
    && tag != 8
    && tag != 9
    && tag != 10
    && tag != 11
    && tag != 12
    && tag != 33
    && tag != 44
    && tag != 55
    && tag != 21
    && tag != 32
    && tag != 43
    && tag != 54
    && tag != 65
    && tag != 66
    && tag != 67
    && tag != 68
    && tag != 69
    && tag != 70
    && tag != 71
    && tag != 72
    && tag != 73
    && tag != 74
    && tag != 75
    && tag != 76 {

    println(tag)
    var tagMinusOne: Int? = Int(item.tag) - 1
    var tagMinusTen: Int? = Int(item.tag) - 10
    var tagMinusEleven: Int? = Int(item.tag) - 11
    var tagMinusTwelve: Int? = Int(item.tag) - 12
    var titleLabel = item.titleLabel?.text
    var minusTwelve: String? = buttonOutlets[tagMinusTwelve!].titleLabel?.text
    var minusOne: String? = buttonOutlets[tagMinusOne!].titleLabel?.text
    println(minusOne)

    }
}
```

Comment: What's your goal? We don't know what you're trying to do so we can't find a modular way to do it.

Comment: You have an error in your boolean logic ... `item.tag != 0 || item.tag != 1` will always be true. It will never reach the `|| item.tag != 2` part.

Comment: What I would really like to do is specify the index number for the buttons that I want that are in the collection outlet instead of referencing the tag but I haven't come to a solution on that either.

Comment: @dreamlax You're right, `&&` is the correct operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two ways. First is with `ClosedIntervals`:

```
(0...10).contains(3) // true
```

Or if you have more complex numbers, you can use contains methods on other CollectionTypes:

```
Set([2, 5, 8]).contains(5) // true
```

Although I'm not sure what you're trying to do. (The statement `x != 0 || x != 1 || x != 2` will return true for every number, for example. Maybe you meant `x != 0 && x != 1 && x != 2`?)

With your edit, the most effecient solution is to create a `Set` of things you want to exclude:

```
var toExclude: Set = [21, 32, 43, 54, 65, 76, 0, 11, 22, 33, 44, 55]

toExclude.unionInPlace(0...10)
toExclude.unionInPlace(66...76)
```

And then the condition in your if statement would be:

```
if !toExclude.contains(item.tag) {...
```